# Using Yamaha YPT-255 Keyboard for Sounddesign

Tags: sound-design, midi, recommendations, usb, keyboard

I recently got a Yahamaha YPT-255 Keyboard.

Now I would like to connect it to my PC in order to record sounds/songs, as well as load sounds I created back to the keyboard.

I noticed that it does not have a MIDI or USB port, it only has an 'AUX in',  'headphones' and 'sustain' ports.

Is there a way to use the Yamaha YPT-255 for designing sounds and songs? If there isn't I would appreciate a suggestion for a keyboard that is suitable to my use case in a similar price range!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can record audio by connecting your headphone output to an audio input on your computer (this works even better for quality and latency if you use a USB interface instead of the basic input jack built into your PC).

If you want to use MIDI, you will need a compatible keyboard and software with soundbanks. M-Audio has a large selection of MIDI controller keyboards available for a range of prices.

If you want something with built-in sounds AND MIDI, you can try to find something 2nd hand, as most newer keyboards with both functions that are really worth buying cost a bit more than your current keyboard.  Hope that helps.